# cakephp form input autoFocus

Tags: cakephp-2.5

I am using cakephp form helper and I want to set the input attribute autoFocus. The best I can get is autoFocus="autoFocus" which is not valid. I need to set it to just autoFocus.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
```

My code is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('title', array('class'=>'form-control','autofocus'));
```

Comment: @TommyDo answer is correct, as said by [dereuromark](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/#autofocus), part of CakePHP dev team.

Comment: @Choma: thank for it. I am just begin to work with CakePHP.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Staff', array('action' => 'login'));
    echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
        'legend' => __(''),
        'username' => array('autofocus'=>'autofocus'),
        'password'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

Comment: The question is labeled for cakephp-2.5, but I've just verified that `['autofocus' => 'autofocus']` also works for 3.3.3

Comment: It's simply add autofocus HTML attribute to HTML tag. So I think it will work for every version. Thank for you verified.

Comment: You can also just set `'autofocus' => true` and cake will do the rest (since Cake 1.2)